# WooCommerce theme declaration doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom theme for my WooCommerce shop. Everything works fine and looks good. The CSS and JS from WooCommerce works. But the status page of WooCommerce says that WooCommerce support is not declared.

If I declare the WooCommerce support with the suggested hook (`add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );`) everything breaks!? The CSS/JS isn't loading andymore.

What's my problem? I couldn't figure it out.
I tried every method from the handbook (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I did not add class `<?php echo body_class(); ?>` to the `<body>`.